# Heroku isn't recognizing my procfile, or my upload isn't working (Play Framework)

Tags: heroku, playframework

I pushed my project using Heroku Push.  https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push
I did the push from the root of my project, at the same level as the app, conf, etc. folders are.

I keep getting an Application error.  The logs show

```
2013-09-08T06:39:53.020323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=projecthuntress.herokuapp.com fwd="70.138.83.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

When I attempt to start a web process, I get the following error:

```
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

My Procfile is a single line

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

When I do a heroku run bash, I get the output

```
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3963
~ $ ls -l
ls -l
total 0
-rw------- 1 u29969 29969 0 Sep  8 06:49 Procfile
```

This confuses me.  Is my Procfile there, or not?  And where did all my other files go?  It should be a full Play deployment.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you just do the usual method of deployment via `git push`?

Comment: I was trying to avoid git... Guess I'll give it a try.

Comment: Now I get a different error.  "App crashed".  How do I view the log to find out what happened?

Comment: Use `heroku logs -t` to tail the logs or `heroku help logs` to get help.

Comment: I used heroku logs to learn that the app crashed.  It doesn't give any more information.

Comment: What version of Play?  For Play 2.x your `Procfile` is wrong.  Check out: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionHeroku for more details on the right syntax.